# Flex and layout (React Native)

Tags: css, react-native, layout, flexbox

I want to space items between them with a fixed size, but the options I'm trying with Flex don't seem to make it work.

I tried these 2 options:

1.

```
alarmContainer: {
    flex: 0,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor:'black',
    margin: 5
  },
  alarmText: {
    fontSize: 17,
    margin: 5
  },
  alarmBtnDelete: {
    margin: 5
  },
  alarmBtnEdit: {
    margin: 5
  }
```

2.

```
alarmContainer: {
    flex: 0,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor:'black',
    margin: 5
  },
  alarmText: {
    fontSize: 17,
    margin: 5
  },
  alarmBtnDelete: {
    margin: 5
  },
  alarmBtnEdit: {
    margin: 5
  }
```

The result I'm getting with option 1 is this:
[image]
The result I'm getting with option 2 is this:
[image]

I want it to be like option 1, just with a little margin between the items. I added margin and padding in each item, but doesn't seem to work, they don't spread.

Comment: Maybe I don't know enough about react, but have you tried putting '%' or 'px' after your margin: 5?

Comment: Yeah, it does nothing, no changes.

Comment: Right, I just saw you're using justify-content. How about setting that to flex-start?
center will hold them all in the center and space-around will put equal space around all items contained in a flex parent.

Comment: I have to leave now, but try setting it to flex-start and adding padding-left to the parent containing all those items, and if that doesn't work then experiment with justify-content set to space-around and set padding-left and padding-right only on the parent containing all those items.

Comment: Setting it to space-around and adding paddingLeft and paddingRight at 30% did the trick! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad you got it working. Don't know why someone downvoted the question; I thought it was fairly written.

Anyway if I were you I would nail down how padding and margin work. Because they can affect most things in the DOM, they are very powerful but also the source of many headaches when you first start working with any new CSS attribute. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dillon.harless found the solution:

```
alarmContainer: {
    flex: 0,
    flexDirection: 'row', // main axis
    justifyContent: 'space-around', // main axis
    alignItems: 'center', // cross axis
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor:'black',
    margin: 5,
    paddingLeft: '30%',
    paddingRight: '30%'
  }
```